# Iphone Objective-C textfield property autocorrectionType and autocapitalizationType not work simultaneous

Tags: iphone

I have faced problem for using textfield property autocorrectionType and autocapitalizationType simultaneous. I used it as following:

```
mytextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
mytextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

whenever i write `mytextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;` then autocapitalizationType property will not be effected.

so, if anyone have idea for "how to use above both property simultaneous" then reply as soon as possible...

Comment: Keyboardtype is Default.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the following correction:

```
mytextField.autocorrectionType = FALSE;
mytextField.autocapitalizationType = FALSE;
```

Comment: autocorrectionType doesn't take a boolean value. It's an enum. `UITextAutocorrectionType`